# Problems including MATLAB "engine.h" for C++ code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, matlab, matlab-engine

I am trying to run the [example code](http://www.mathworks.es/help/techdoc/matlab_external/rmvd_matlablink__98.html) from the MATLAB Doc, but when I try to build the project in Visual Studio I get this error

```
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'engine.h': No such file or directory
```

The fact is that in the Doc I cannot find where to find the header to link it, they show the examples as if there was no need to do anything else, just do the

```
#include "engine.h";
```

Any ideas about how to solve this issue?

**EDIT**

I solved the first problem but now I get some errors reated to missing libs:

```
1>engwindemo.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _engClose referenced in function _main
1>engwindemo.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mxGetClassName referenced in function _main
1>engwindemo.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _engGetVariable referenced in function _main
1>engwindemo.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _engOutputBuffer referenced in function _main
1>engwindemo.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mxDestroyArray referenced in function _main
1>engwindemo.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _engEvalString referenced in function _main
1>engwindemo.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _engPutVariable referenced in function _main
1>engwindemo.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mxGetPr referenced in function _main
1>engwindemo.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mxCreateDoubleMatrix_730 referenced in function _main
1>engwindemo.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _engOpen referenced in function _main
```

I set the Path variable as told in the documentation, set the lib path and added some libraries and now I don't know what else can I do. I also rebooted VisualStudio in order to make the Path variable change effective.

[image]
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I finaly solved the problem. I was building a WIN32 project, while matlab is x64, so VisualStudio gives errors when you try to link 64-bit platforms. The solution is changing the Active Solution Platform to x64, inside Project Properties -> Configuration Manager.

It is well explained in the following [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yb4317s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Thanks anyway for the answers, they were useful.

So, summarizing, to be able to compile and run a c++ code in VisualStudio2008 and Matlab2010 with engine.h, the following steps are required:

1.- Set Path variable in Advanced System Settings-> environment variables: **C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a\bin\win64** (or the path where libeng.dll is located)

2.- In project properties of VisualStudio, link in Additional Include directories of C++->General:
**"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a\extern\include"**

3.- In project properties, linker->general, Additional Library Directories:
**"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a\extern\lib\win64\microsoft"**

4.- Add the following libraries in Linker->Additional Dependencies:
**libeng.lib
libmx.lib**

5.- Change the Active Solution Platform to x64, in Configuration Manager as explained in the link.

Answer (score 2):

Have you added the MATLAB include directory to your project's include path?
[image]. The directory should be like "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a\extern\include"

Comment: But which is the include directory exactly? I cannot find it inside Matlab folders.

Comment: Like "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a\extern\include"

Answer (score 0):

In case you forgot, add the folder containing libmat.dll libmx.dll etc. to your path. For me that was:

> C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012a\bin\win64

Answer (score 0):

While the [Jav_Rock's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8802103/4960953) is completely correct, I want to add information about one of the points:

> 1.- Set Path variable in Advanced System Settings-> environment variables: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a\bin\win64 (or the path where
>   libeng.dll is located)

I spent three hours to understant what does it means, so I want to clarify this moment for future researchers.
You need to add the path of MATLAB Engine dll libraries to your Windows. 
We can do it this way:

My Computer -> right click: Settings. Opened System window. Left bottom corner: Advanced System Settings

[image]

Advanced Tab

[image]

In the Environment variables for your user press Create... button and add this one:
Variable name: PATH
Variable value: **C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\bin\win64**

This path is reference on where is your libeng.dll located.
Important moment: it can require to restart VS or even restart computer.