# what is the way for solving link errors for matlab R2012a with visual studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, 32-bit, matlab-engine

Using visual studio 2010 and Matlab R2012a (32 -bit) and on a 32bit platform:

I want just to call a function from matlab in c++ using matlab engine. 
I get the matlab function output in a separate solution and it works well; 
I did the same setting in my main project such as setting the additional include path and additional library path and also I set the linker inputs. 
also I set the path environment variable for operating system. 
but it does not work!
my code is :

```
double* P::FindingCameraPosition()
    {


          double Result[6];
          Engine *ep;
          if (!(ep = engOpen(""))) 
          {
            cout<<"Error in starting matlab engine!"<<endl; 
          }
          double *cresult; 

          mxArray *mresult; 
          mresult = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1,1,mxREAL);

          engEvalString(ep , "z=Position()");
          mresult = engGetVariable(ep,"z");
          cresult = mxGetPr(mresult);

          for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
          {
              Result[i] = cresult[i];
          }
          engClose(ep);

          return Result;
    }
```

I see these errors :

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _engClose
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _engEvalString
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _engGetVariable
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _engOpen
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mxCreateDoubleMatrix_730
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mxGetPr
```

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20538316/cannot-run-a-project-because-of-matlab-api-link-problems) and it did not help me at all; 
all of the others who faced these errors, missed the step of adding libraries to the linker input; but I set it and checked it several times;

why it is work as a separate project and does not work in another solution? I got confused!
I am using the openGL32 in my project. so I guess that using opengl and matlab engine has not compatibality with each other;

Can you suggest me the ways you tried before?

thank you so much!

Comment: Please check if everything is set to 32-bit, especially project which you build in Visual Studio (Active Solution Platform in Project Properties -> Configuration Manager).

Comment: Check also [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8800439/problems-including-matlab-engine-h-for-c-code?rq=1).

Comment: thank you so much ;) I checked its running on Win32 and linker is set for all configuration. but this errors does not solve :(

Comment: I checked your link before but it did not help me ...